# How is this scrolling/joining effect achieved?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I was wondering if someone could point me in the direction to achieve the same sort of scrolling/joining effect of ths site:

http://www.puma.com/actvrcvr/#/home

Where the page is split in two horizontally, and each side moves independently and join up as you scroll. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried viewing page source and pulling the JavaScript behind to have a look?

Comment: yep but don't see any code I can look at really

Comment: Try looking at lines 66/67 of the code.  It users a couple of libraries to update the display and get/put data.  If you're looking using FireFox you should be able to click the link to open the library it uses.

Comment: You can get a very similar effect by doing it with multiscroll.js plugin: http://alvarotrigo.com/multiScroll

Answer (score 0):

You can do something very similar by using [multiscroll.js plugin](http://alvarotrigo.com/multiScroll/).